# Modifying a voltage suitable for input to an ESP32

Tags: digital-logic, esp32

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but that is what I am !
I am constructing a circuit to input to an ESP32 using this device bought on E--y.
https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07WLTG1KL/ref=pe_27063361_485629781_TE_item
Its OFF/ON voltages are 3.5V and 2.7V.
I am concerned that 2.7V is too high for a 'LOW' for the ESP, how can I get it closer to 0V?
Thanks

Comment: The output voltages should be 0V and supply voltage like 3.3V, if you used a 3.3V supply. If those voltages you gave are true, there is a problem, but given no info, impossible to say what problem it is, where it is, and how to fix it.

Comment: Since you already bought it can you measure the voltage? it actually was 2.7V, or did you read this number somewhere? I don't see it on the Amazon page.

Comment: The voltages at this point are irrelevant unless you post a schematic. The description states: "Output Format: digital output (0 and 1)" The voltages will be relative to the VCC supply voltage. These are hobby devices do not expect super accuracy. To me  it appears you run it off the same VCC as the ESP the output will be compatible with one of the digital GPIOs.

Comment: I think it depends on the used Vcc, like 3.3 or 5V. If you use 3.3V, probably that range drops.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. The Vcc I am using is from a Linear Bench PSU set to 3.5V and the voltages given I have measured with my Fluke True RMS meter. It is intended that it will share the ESP's voltage supply. Apart from the LED on the board it looks like DO is directly off the LM393, I haven't yet tried to trace the actual circuit, perhaps that will have to be my next step.